# Best Dot.Net eCommerce Open Source that connects successfully with QuickBooks

Tags: c#, e-commerce, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

It seems that there are many Dot.Net Open Source "eCommerce" sites out there but few might be connecting successfully to QuickBooks.

...and I don't know which ones :--)

Any help will be truly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Very old question but [nopCommerce](http://www.nopcommerce.com/default.aspx) has a connection to QuickBooks :)

Comment: Yes ...but does it really work? I read in many places it does not. Also I believe the way it works is by expecting you to have the MAIN QuickBooks file on the Server for it to be directly connected to the Web Server running your eCommerce.

Is that right ?